Unable to do TLS handshake to NGINX server
After setting up a nginx server, I tried to access via https by curl or openssl s_client but it fail. I can only use curl with http://...
When I use openssl s_client -connect  www.SEexample.com:443 -showcerts
The error shows
40570C4DB47F0000:error:0A000126:SSL routines:ssl3_read_n:unexpected eof while reading:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:308:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 326 bytes
Verification: OK

Here is the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

ssl_engine pkcs11;

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    server_name www.SEexample.com SEexample.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/SEcombine2.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/www.SEexample.com.key2.pem;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/SEcombine2.crt;
    }


    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';


    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

Noted that I already verify the certificate key and certificate.
Please give me an useful leads.

Check the error logs at the server. Common problems are the the certificates are not there, cannot be read, are somehow wrong ... Also, what is the intention of your ssl_engine pkcs11; setting, when you provide certificate and key as files. Seems to be wrong.

@SteffenUllrich you arre correct. I should remove that ssl_engine, and it works with the command "openssl s_client -connect  www.SEexample.com:443 -showcerts".
The curl one still has another issue, and later on I will change the file to pkcs11 URI. Thank you for the helpful comment.
